# array data is showing in console but when i printing in html it is not showing empty array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting data from a file then that data is pushing to array.array data can view in console but that data is not displaying in html page.
If i use any button then i able to see that data in html page.

```js
var app = angular.module('xlsxApp', []);
app.controller('xlsxCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.finaldata = [];
  $scope.UploadFiles = function(files) {
    var f = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      /*Converts the excel data in to object*/
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
      });
      /*Gets all the sheetnames of excel in to a variable*/
      var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
      /*This is used for restricting the script to consider only first sheet of excel*/
      sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) { /*Iterate through all sheets*/
        /*Convert the cell value to Json*/
        var exceljson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
        $scope.finaldata = exceljson;
        console.log("finaldata :: ", $scope.finaldata);
      });
    }
  }
  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log("finaldata :: ", $scope.finaldata);
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.core.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="xlsxApp" ng-controller="xlsxCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="excelfile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().UploadFiles(this.files)" />

    </div>
    <button ng-click="test()">preview</button>
    {{finaldata[0]}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `onload` is asynchronous

Comment: how to change above code in angularjs

Comment: when i upload a file then i am pushing to $scope.finaldata array but that data is not showing in html page but it showing in console

Comment: if i upload file in console array data is showing but not showing html,but if we press preview button then it showing the data but did not write any function to view the data

Comment: Try `$timeout(function(){ $scope.finaldata = exceljson; }, 0)`

Comment: finally it is working...thank u bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reader.onload()` is evaluated outside the AngularJS environment. You should can `$timeout` service to update the UI view in next digest cycle

```
$timeout(function(){ 
    $scope.finaldata = exceljson; 
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you get the object in console not an array.so,in html you bind {{finaldata}}/if you want value {{finaldata['C']}}

Comment: if i upload file in console array data is showing but not showing html,but if we press preview button then it showing the data but did not write any function to view the data

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$scope.apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to evaluate changes coming from outside `angular.js`

The reason why you see result when press a button - you probably have `ng-click` on the button that implicitly runs through `$scope.apply()` and applies your changes already sitting in the scope.